# PHP appears to have session files in two different locations?

Tags: php, session

I have a CentOS 6 box running nginx and PHP 7.2.

My php 7.2 session files exist where I expect them to, in

`/var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session`

However, I've just noticed that a smaller number of them exist in

`/tmp`

I only have one version of php installed, running a number of sites.  `phpInfo();` reports the first directory for each site.  I can't find any reference to `/tmp` regarding sessions at all.

I have discovered that if I run `php -r 'phpInfo();' | grep save_path` I get `session.save_path => no value => no value`, so I guess that's causing it?  I.e. my cron jobs are creating the empty session files.

Is this normal?  If so, why?  Why does php run from the command line not use the value set in php.ini?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes.

This is documented in the configuration file.
Each user must have a different location to avoid access issues.

So the path is configured in each SAPI file

Default to `/tmp` (for CLI users)

See these comments in your php.ini:

```
; RPM note : session directory must be owned by process owner
; for mod_php, see /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
; for php-fpm, see /etc/php-fpm.d/*conf
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

It means that `/var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session` is only used by the `apache` user (the default user in the FPM pools of your distribution).

And if you use multiple FPM pools, running with different users, you have to set a different location for each, see `php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
; Set the following data paths to directories owned by the FPM process user.
;
; Do not change the ownership of existing system directories, if the process
; user does not have write permission, create dedicated directories for this
; purpose.
;
; See warning about choosing the location of these directories on your system
; at http://php.net/session.save-path
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
;php_value[opcache.file_cache]  = /var/lib/php/opcache
```

Comment: So if I wanted to change the save path for cli, where would I do that?  Also what's your opinion on the save path for apache?  I assume it's bad practice to try to put the session files in ram due to losing them in the event of a reboot.  The performance gain would be pretty minor I guess?  Thanks @Remi Collet!

Comment: For CLI => php.ini (or php-cli.ini). Indeed I think perf. gain will be small (excepted if file are very big, which is a bad practice)

Comment: What does uncommenting the last line php_value[opcache.file_cache]  do? Are we supposed to uncomment when opcache is enabled?

Comment: When opcache.file_cache is set, it enables file cache on disk. Which is a way to have a faster server after a restart (cache is persistent). Must be considered experimental in early version.

Comment: @RemiCollet was you triggered by /var/opt/remi? :) I think it could be useful to declare in your answer that you are part of that project. Just to give more authority (who can do it more than the author...  ihihih) thank you!